# MS Access - Show/hide label based on checkbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to print a label on a report only if a checkbox is checked.
I've tried many different lines of code but I can't get it to work. This is what I have at the moment (on the OnFormat event of the footer of my report):

```
If chkSignature = True Then
  CEOsign.Visible = True
Else
  CEOsign.Visible = False
End If
```

and this is a [working example](https://my.syncplicity.com/share/dar002ji5f77shx/test) you can play with.

If the checkbox is ticked I want to print the label for the signature. If the checkbox is unticked I want to hide it. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your code works correctly if you Print Preview, or Print.  Try placing your code in the Report_Activate event.

Comment: Assuming the checkbox is bound to the report's query, you can apply conditional formating to the control based on expression e.g. `[CheckBoxField] = -1` to make it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't download the file, but I am guessing you are not changing the checkbox during the right event. As I recall, Detail_Format is the right event in which to place this code if you want to change visibility of items in the Detail section. MS Access is sometimes finicky, however, and I recall times when this sort of task did not go smoothly. Good luck!